# How to filter existing measures created using DAX in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created two measures

```
#SavingsLocal = 

    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Savings'[sum(Risk Percentage*USLP Savings)]),
        FILTER(ALL('Savings'),SEARCH("NO",'Savings'[ICB],,BLANK()) && SEARCH("YTD",'Savings'[Scenario],,BLANK())))
```

and

```
#SavingsGlobal = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Savings'[sum(Risk Percentage*USLP Savings)]),
    FILTER(ALL('Savings'),SEARCH("YES",'Savings'[ICB],,BLANK()) && SEARCH("YTD",'Savings'[Scenario],,BLANK())))
```

Now if my Region column present in the Savings Table is "GLOBAL", I want to use my #SavingsGlobal else #SavingsLocal

I created a calculated column for this

```
#finalsavings = IF(Savings[Location - Region (L1)] == "GLOBAL",Savings[#SavingsGlobal],Savings[#SavingsLocal])
```

but this does not seem to work at all, its giving me a value for Global but for others I am getting a same value.

How do I approach this using DAX?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated measure that combines the two:

```
#finalsavings = 
  IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Savings[Location - Region (L1)]) == "Global",
      Savings[#SavingsGlobal],
      Savings[#SavingsLocal])
```

Comment: hi! this worked very smoothly. Thank you sooo much for this.

Comment: Done. Was struggling with this measure since hours.

Comment: Hi , I was wrong, this measure is NOT WORKING. I am not getting the value under GLOBAL cluster but getting values under LOCAL.

Comment: Is the #SavingsLocal by itself working? try using CONTAINSSTRING instead of SEARCH